# How do I access the variable from another function using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to access a variable that I set in a function from another function.
After logging in, I tried store the variable 'username' into a global variable window.username. I want to access this variable in another function when the client presses the 'recommend-btn'. However, when I console.log() the username in the other function it says it is undefined.

How do I access the variable 'username'?

```
$(function () {
  let username = ''

  $('#login-button').on('click', async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    username = $('#username').val()
    window.username = username

  })

  // recommend groups to the user
  $('#recommend-btn').on('click', async function (event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    // hide the create group section
    $('#create-group').hide()
    // hide the view groups button and show the groups
    $('#view-group-btn').hide()
    $('#view-group').show()

    const username = window.username
    console.log(username)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this

Also why async? what is the point here?

This is in the same page

```js
$(function() {
  let username = ''

  $('#login-button').on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    username = $('#username').val(); // setting the global var
  })

  // recommend groups to the user
  $('#recommend-btn').on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const uname = username; // getting the global var
    console.log(uname)
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="username" />
<button id="login-button" type="button">Login</button>
<button id="recommend-btn" type="button">Recommend</button>
```

This is in different pages

```js
$(function() {
  let username = localStorage.getItem("username") || ""; // loads username from localstorage in EITHER Page
  $('#username').val(username); // if exists
  $('#login-button').on('click', e => {
    localStorage.setItem("username", $('#username').val());
  })

// other page

  $('#recommend-btn').on('click', e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    console.log(username)
  })
})
```

Comment: When I do this, it logs an empty string. Also, the login-button is in a separate html file to the recommend-btn. does that have something to do with it? I can still access the username when it is in the $('#login-button') function though.

Comment: This makes absolutely no sense. The snippet I wrote works. If the buttons are in different files, how (except for wishful thinking) would you expect one setting something and magically it is available in a completely different file not loaded at the same time???? The window scope is not cross reload. Use localStorage if you want to save the user name across page loads

Comment: But what I shared with you is the exact file that I have. i.e. even though the two buttons are in different files, I am able to access the username from the function $('#login-button'). Therefore, it is present in the same file that the $('#recommend-btn') is in. All that is required is to get the username variable to the $('#recommend-btn') function but it is not working

Comment: username is cleared when the other page loads! It is not magically transported around unless it is hardcoded in the file. See second script for localStorage

Comment: What I shared in my question is in one file. All I am saying is that the login button is in HTML file A and the recommend button is in HTML file B. But there is only one JavaScript file

Comment: Yes but the vars are NOT SHARED. If you set a var in one page, then it is NOT AVAILABLE in the other page, just because the share CODE. They do not share VALUES!!